# php script running when cron job already deleted

Tags: php, cron

I am doing a testing a `cron-job` on a shared hosting on `hostgator`. I am using this simple and short php script which sends email everytime it gets executed via cron. To keep things explicit, I record the timestamp and timezone and send to email as subject and message.

```
$message = 'Default timezone : ' . date_default_timezone_get(); 
$subject = 'DateTime : ' .date('m/d/Y H:i:s', time()); 
mail("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com", $subject, $message);
```

`*/20 * * * *  wget http://path/to/cron.php` test script executed every 20 minutes.

---

ISSUE : I deleted the cron job from cpanel about two hours ago and I am still getting emails with the rate of roughly around one email per minute. What is happening here, where should I look for the mistake ?

[image]

**Note** : Please state the reason for downvote if you must, so i know the mistake in my question and have a chance to correct it.

Comment: no one would visit the link to the script, it is not provided in the fronted and is a part of a wordpress plugin. Even if someone visiting, why would they visit in almost regular intervals of around 1 minute ?

Comment: Could it be the robots executing the script ??

Comment: change the name of the script. maybe you or someone or someprogram is mistakenly executing it

Comment: that could be an idea. i will do that and revert. thnx

Comment: @DarshanJain Well, the emails has stopped. I dug a little more and found that wordpress has a file called cron.php which may be causing name collision and hence the repeated execution of the script. 

Please create an answer of your comment. Solution may get buried in the comments. Lets mark this solved. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the name of the script to `corn1.php` or else.

There may be some conflict with other codes, or maybe someone else came to know about that script.